# How can I detect current user's User-Group in Spartacus

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I have a requirement to get the current user's User-Group in Angular Application with Spartacus.

I saw, there are OOTB controllers inside Hybris but no way to call them from spartacus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use B2BUserService. There is a method designed to load and return that data:

```
  getUserGroups(
    orgCustomerId: string,
    params: SearchConfig
  ): Observable<EntitiesModel<UserGroup>>
```